# Updating w2p table with MySQL data

Tags: mysql, web2py

I'm a beginner with w2p and MySQL. I managed to create a webpage where I list the computers I manage with some of their properties. As with more machines updating the table for my computers became cumbersome I created a MySQL db on of Linux boxes which is updated by a powershell script that collects the properties I'm interested in. Effectively I've got the w2p manually updated table that I would now want to get updated from the MySQL db. After lots of googling I found how to connect to the external db. In my default.py

```
def windows_db():
statusdb = MySQLdb.connect(host="linux1.domain.net",  
    port=3306,
    user="user1", 
    passwd="passwd", 
    db="my") 
cur = statusdb.cursor() 
comps = db(db.windows_comps.id>0).select(db.windows_comps.hostname,distinct=True, orderby=db.windows_comps.hostname)
```

This is as far as I get. For each hostname I would need to find a row in the MySQL db with the same hostname and update the values in my w2p table. How do I get there?

Comment: What do you mean by your "w2p table"? Are you saying you used the web2py DAL to create a SQLite database (i.e., is that what `db` is in your code)? Note, to make things easier, you can also just as easily use the DAL to connect to your MySQL database (you can either use that database exclusively or use it as well as your SQLite database).

Comment: That's right the db is the web2py defined table. How can the DAL connect to the MySQL please?

Comment: Is there any reason you need two separate databases, or can you simply do everything with the MySQL database?

Comment: The webpage started as manual table. Problem is some of the fields I defined in DAL cannot be automated so I need that to stay to be able to change them manually when needed. That's the only reason I guess.

Comment: I modified the comps variable to be only  `comps = db(db.windows_comps.id>0).select()                                                                                                                           for computers in comps:                                                                                                           cur.execute("select biosfw from extcomps where extcomps.hostname = '"+comps.Hostname+"'")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        if rows:
            list.append(rows)`   This allows me to view all matches in a separate view so one step forward :)

Comment: The question is, why do you need the SQLite database at all? Why not store everything in MySQL and use the web2py DAL connect to the MySQL database directly? Then you can just make updates directly in MySQL?

Comment: Sorry for such late response. Holiday thing. It's because I won't be the only person that would need to update the manual fields. I wouldn't want all involved to have direct access to the db.